# Is it possible to create dictionary with input, where if we input a key. output returns value of that key?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

In this example I want to make simple "contacts", but when I input for example john, output gives me n1, where n is last letter of john.

(if you know better way to do it without my hilarious code, also let me know)

```
nums = {
    'john': '1',
    'mary': '2',
    'jake': '3'
}

name = ''
while name != 'exit':
    name = input('Name: ')
    output = ''
    for output in name:
        if name == 'exit':
            break
        output += nums.get(name, ' (not exist)') + ' '
    print(output)
```

Comment: What is the expected output @K.Gava ?

Comment: Only value @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: remove `for output in name` because this get chars from string. Use `print(output)` to see it.

Comment: Got it! You don't need the for loop, just `in` operator is enough to check membership in dict for name! @K.Gava . Check below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some problems

1. Your for loop `for output in name:` is unnecessary, since it is iterating over characters of string `name`, but you don't need to do that
2. After the loop is done, output has the value of the last character of the `name`, e.g. `output='n'` for `john` hence you see `n1` in your output

So you can fix your code by running by asking for name in an infinite loop, then you break the loop and exit when someone types `exit`, otherwise you get the element from the dictionary via `nums.get` and print it

```
nums = {
    'john': '1',
    'mary': '2',
    'jake': '3'
}

name = ''

#Run an infinite loop
while True:

    #Get the name from user
    name = input('Name: ')

    #If user types exit, break the loop
    if name == 'exit':
        break
    #Otherwise either print the number of not exist
    print(nums.get(name, ' (not exist)'))
```

The output will look like

```
Name: john
1
Name: mary
2
Name: jake
3
Name: joe
 (not exist)
Name: exit
```

Comment: Glad to help! It would be great that if the answer helped you, you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer @K.Gava :)

Answer (score 2):

**Problems**:

- A loop inside `while` is not required. `for output in name:` actually iterates through each character of `name`, which is not what you want.
- `output += ...` inside the `for` loop will at the end takes last letter of key and append the value, which is why you got `'n1'` for `'john'`.

**Code**:

```
while True:
    name = input('Name: ')
    if name.lower() == 'exit':
        break
    output = nums.get(name, ' (not exist)')
    print(output)
```